# Highcharts: plot a number that was too small to detect?

Tags: highcharts

I am plotting values on a Highchart for my client. Sometimes she tests for something and the resulting number is too small to be detected (so she doesn't give me a number value). She doesn't want the chart to show a zero, but rather a "non-detect." Does anyone have ideas how to show that?

For example, how do I plot something like "if <.5 then display '<0.5' instead of a number"?

[Here are the tables that I am converting into Highcharts](https://deq.utah.gov/water-quality/utah-lake-algal-bloom-monitoring-2020) (specifically the Microcystin test). The Highcharts are powered by parsing .csv files with PHP. If a value says "<0.5", then I don't want it to be a zero. I want people to know that the test was run, but that the level was too low to register. For now, I'm telling my client to explain that using introductory text, but thought maybe one of you would have a better idea for communicating this.

Note: I can see that she reported a .29 (which is smaller than .5). That looks inconsistent with what I'm asking. Apparently that was tested with a more sensitive test (so it is a valid plot).

Example series:
0.2,
0.66,
23.3,
1.64,
0.29,
<0.5,
0.58,
464,
93.2,
22.9

Comment: Hi @red5, Could you provide me with a sample of such data set?

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I edited my question to include the series numbers and a link to the page where my Highcharts will be published.

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4n5oey70/ - you can mock data labels and a tooltip. Did you want to achieve something like this?

Comment: @ppotaczek This is a helpful start. Sometimes, a value less than .5 is valid. Is there a way to use a string or placeholder in a series for the cases that are not valid? If the value is a number, then I could plot it as that number. If it's a placeholder, then I could do as you suggest and plot as .5 but customize the pointFormatter like you demonstrate.

Comment: You need to use some small number for such values. For example if the value is not valid use: `0.01` and the result will be the same.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you for taking the time to help. If it's not possible to use a string or placeholder, then do you want to add that as an answer to my original question, along with your jsfiddle example and I'll mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert such values into very small numbers and show them as data labels and in a tooltip as a `<0.5` value.

```
var data = [0.2, 0.66, 23.3, 1.64, 0.29, '<0.5', 0.58, 464, 93.2, 22.9];

data = data.map(el => isNaN(el) ? 0.0001 : el);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: data,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                if (this.y < 0.5) {
                    return '< 0.5'
                }

                return this.y;
            }
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
            var pointVal = this.y < 0.5 ? '< 0.5' : this.y;
            return '<span style="color:' + this.color + '">●</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + pointVal + '</b><br/>'
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0q864fx2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter